# How to store CS and IP addresses (Intel 8086)?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I would like to store CS (code segment) and IP (instruction pointer) addresses to any of available registers AX, BX, CX or DX. Is it possible somehow to access current CS or IP values?

Comment: Note that call/pop unbalanced the return address predictor stack.  If you're writing high-performance 16-bit code for modern CPUs, consider `call` / `mov bx, [bp-something]` / `ret`, where the callee depends on the distance from BP to SP in the caller.  (Or consider using x86-64 instead, where RIP-relative addressing modes and LEA solve this problem more efficiently, and you can generally make faster code.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `CS` is directly accessible. `IP`, however, isn't. The usual trick is to do a `CALL` instruction which will place it on the stack:

```
    mov dx, cs ; save cs into dx
    call next
next:
    pop ax ; place ip of "next" into ax, adjust as necessary
```

Of course this is only needed if the load address is not known.

Comment: Ahh. I forgot this, thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to obtain the IP is this:

CALL getIP

getIP:

mov bx, [sp] ; Read the return address into BX.

RET

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: `mov bx, [sp]` isn't valid in 16-bit 8086 code. In particular `[sp]` is not a valid memory operand since `sp` can't be used although `bp` can.

Comment: This avoids unbalancing the return-address predictor stack, so it's faster on modern CPUs.  [Reading program counter directly](//stackoverflow.com/q/599968).  `mov bx, sp` / `mov bx, [ss:bx]` would do the trick here.